# How to Cut & Ripple Delete on a german laptop keyboard?

Tags: davinci-resolve, keyboard-shortcut

I am using my windows laptop for video editing and recently came across this incredibly time saving feature:

Cut & Ripple Delete, which basically does 3 actions in one. You can see in this guide at 4:48 how this command is used:

Unfortunately there seem to be problems with the german keyboard. The english shortcut is:

**Ctrl + Shift + [**
But it doesn't work on a german keyboard. The problem seems to be that on a german keyboard you have to press an extra **Alt** key to be able to type **[**.

The keyboard customization settings in Resolve 16 do not even show this command (Cut & Ripple Delete). I don't know if I'm stupid or what but I am having tremendous issues setting a new shortcut for ANY command.

Does a shortcut for Cut & Ripple Delete exist on the german keyboard that actually works? Can I make this work in Resolve without setting my system keyboard localization to english?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The commands you're looking for are:

**End to Playhead** - in Application/Trim/Ripple

**Start to Playhead** - in Application/Trim/Ripple

Put them on some shortcut that is actually working on the german keyboard.